# String is being wrongly printed

Tags: python, python-2.7

String is being wrongly printed, please tell me the code change that is necessary. I am a beginner in python.

```
    command2 = "  –o -d  Current"
    print(command2)
```

I wish to print "  –o -d  Current" but I am getting "  ?o -d  Current" as output

Comment: Try escaping your spaces and special characters with `\\`

Comment: That thing before the `o` isn't a hyphen. Did you *want* a hyphen?

Comment: ok, I see it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed the first character in front of O to '-' and the code worked fine.